# Jest coverage missing only the if condition line in a weird way - why and how to fix

Tags: javascript, jestjs, enzyme

I have a index.js which looks like

```
...
[line 69] if A:
[line 70]    foo()
[line 71] else if B:
[line 72]    bar()
```

I have written a test for line 69 - 70, the evidence is if I comment it out, the yarn test --coverage will show line 69, 70 missing.

However, even with this test, the coverage complains line 69 is missing

Another thing I noticed is that if I swap the if conditions to

```
...
[line 69] if B:
[line 70]    bar()
[line 71] else if A:
[line 72]    foo()
```

It is still line 69 missing in coverage

What is the reason for this in jest? How can I fix that?

Comment: That isn't valid [if...else syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) in JavaScript...

Comment: if you mean the parentheses - they are psedo code, more for logic

Comment: Can you share `A` and `B`?  They are both on a single line?  I can't recreate that issue.  If `A` is something like `(true || (() => true)())` and the [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) is on its own line then it will be reported as uncovered, but I can't recreate the issue if the entire condition is on the same line.

Comment: Hi Brain, thanks for the reply. I figured out the reason. I didn't have an `else` clause to cover the rest.  The if and else if have actually both been covered. But there should be something to cover the rest

Comment: Even if the else statement is missing and empty, you still need to launch a test for `!A && !B`, which will trigger the else empty branch on Istanbul standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are really three branches here: either `if` gets triggered, or `else if`, or neither.

Even though the latter case is empty in this case (as there is no `else` statement) you still need a test where neither `if` or `else if` gets triggered for full coverage.